# Kivy Popup and Drag Behavior

Tags: python, kivy

So I am very new to Kivy, and it is pretty frustrating so far.....anyway, I am trying to now make a popup that I can drag and move around, and I don't understand what is going on.... when I call popup.open() in the onButtonPress function, the popup is closeable through the dismiss action, though I lose dragable functionality....when I add the popup directly to the main window through self.layout.add_widget(popup), I am able to move the popup but then am not able to close it....I'm guessing the open() call is redefining the dragable window? Is this true? If not what is happening and how do I fix it?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout 
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup 

class PopupExample(App): 
    # override the build method and return the root widget of this App 
  
    def build(self): 
        # Define a grid layout for this App 
        self.layout = FloatLayout() 
  
  
        # Add a button 
        self.button = Button(text ="Click for pop-up") 
        self.layout.add_widget(self.button) 
  
        # Attach a callback for the button press event 
        
        self.button.bind(on_press = self.onButtonPress) 
          
        return self.layout 
  
    def onButtonPress(self, button): 
       # print('opening')
        layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, padding = 10) 
        img = Image(source="temp_plot.png")
        closeButton = Button(text = "Close the pop-up")
        layout.add_widget(img)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)
        popup = MoveableImage( title ='Demo Popup', content = layout, size_hint =(None, None), size = (400,400))
        popup.open()
        #self.layout.add_widget(popup)
        #closeButton.bind(on_press = self.remove_widget(popup))



class MoveableImage(DragBehavior,Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoveableImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.drag_timeout = 10000000
        self.drag_distance = 0
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]

        

  
# Run the app 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    PopupExample().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to drag the `Popup`, adding it to the `App` `layout` is probably the best way to go. Of course, then you don't really need to use the `Popup`, just use some `Layout`. If you go that route, deleting the `Popup` can be accomplished by defining the `Button` binding like this:

```
closeButton.bind(on_press = lambda x: self.layout.remove_widget(popup))
```

The `lambda` is just there to suck up the button instance arg that `on_press` adds, so you won't get errors about too many arguments to the `remove_widget()` method.

The `modalView` class (base of the `Popup`) has a method that keeps the `Popup` centered. Looks like the `DragBehavior` will work, if you over-ride that method. So, if your add:

```
def _align_center(self, *l):
    pass
```

to your `MoveableImage` class, I think you will then be able to drag it. The `open()` method of the `ModalView` does some bindings to insure that the `_align_center()` method is called on any position or size change. Since adding the `Popup` to a `Layout` does not call the `open()` method, those bindings are never set up.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I had tried the self.layout.remove_widget(popup) and got an error that you mentioned....do you have any ideas as to why the Popup.open() causes the Popup to no longer be draggable?

Comment: I have added to my answer.

Comment: Awesome thank you, you have been so helpful with this!